# Change of Variable for Shifted Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability, functions, transformation

The shifted exponential distribution is given by

$$f(t) = \mu  \exp [-\mu  (t-\theta )]$$

with domain of support given by $t \in [\theta, \infty),\ \theta \geq 0$.

I want to do a change of variable to eliminate the $t - \theta$.

So, Let $x = t - \theta$, then $dx = dt$, and the limits of integration become $0$ and $\infty$. That is, the transformed function becomes

$$f(x) = \mu  \exp [-\mu\  x ]$$

with domain of support  $x \in [0, \infty)$, which is the exponential distribution.

Is this correct? It seems like I'm made a mistake somewhere...I.e., the $\theta$ disappeared...

Comment: By making this substitution, aren't you trying to make the $\theta$ disappear?

Comment: Yes, but I would expect $\theta$ to be somewhere in the bounds of integration. Also, just because a function is transformed, shouldn't they have the same mean? I.e., $E[f(t)] = \theta + \frac{1}{\mu}$ while $E[f(x)] = \frac{1}{\mu}$. I must be misunderstanding something about transforming functions...

Comment: No, in this case it doesn't appear in the integral since it is just a linear shift, and originally, it is the lower bound, and doing this substitution removes it from the lower bound. Also, a transformation can change the mean, and often does, since you are shifting the pdf. Another example of this is a normal distribution, with mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$. $$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2), Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\implies Z\sim(0,1)$$ So both the mean and variance are changed by this transformation.

Comment: Ok - that make sense now - Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community Wiki answer to close this.

> I want to do a change of variable to eliminate the $t−θ$.
>
> ...
>
> Is this correct? It seems like I'm made a mistake somewhere...I.e., the $θ$
> disappeared...

Why, yes, if you shift to eliminate the shift parameter, $\theta$, then the $\theta$ will vanish.   That is the point.

So indeed, since this is a linear shift on the axis, whith no distortion of the curve, the required *probability density function* is obtained via an inline replacement: $t\gets (t_\star+\theta)$ .

$$~f_{T_\star}(t_\star)~{=~f_T(t_\star+\theta) \\[1ex] =~\mu \exp(-\mu(t_\star+\theta-\theta))~\mathbf 1_{(t_\star+\theta)\in[\theta;\infty)}\\[1ex]=~ \mu\exp(-\mu t_\star)~\mathbf 1_{t_\star\in[0;\infty)}}$$

Which is an *unshifted exponential* distribution, as should be anticipated.

> Also, just because a function is transformed, shouldn't they have the same mean?

Oh, no, not at all.   Since the function is *transformed*, a transformation should occur.

Well, to be precise, in a *linear shift*, only the mean changes (it is shifted!), while variance and other *centred* moments remain untouched, as they describe shape of the curve, which is unchanged by a shift.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(T_\star)~&=~\mathsf E(T)-\theta \\[1ex] \mathsf{Var}(T_\star)~&{=~ \mathsf E((T-\theta-\mathsf E(T-\theta))^2)\\[1ex] =~ \mathsf {Var}(T)}\\ \textit{et cetera}~~&\ldots\end{align}$$

That is all.